# can't commit file using subversion in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

Novice eclipse/subversion user here... I'm working on an Android project and have 3 database files in the assets folder. I've made some changes to the databases but now I'm unable to commit the changes in subversion (using subversive plugin). I'm able to commit all my other files just fine but when I try to commit the databases (right-click in package explorer, Team > Commit...), the '>' marker never goes away. Also, the database files used to commit just fine, this problem just recently happened. Is there some log file I can check for errors or some view I can open with more detail? (I didn't see anything in LogCat.)

Comment: Can you see the subversion output window in Eclipse? There should be a "Subversion console" tab. If not, perhaps check through the "Windows/" menu (on the menu bar of Eclipse) to locate it. 

(LogCat is just what's happening on your device; hopefully, you're not running Subversion on your phone ;-) )

Comment: Great, thank you!! I found the subversion console window - I knew there had to be something like that. Anyway, it says the file is "out-of-date; try updating", which is odd because I know I have the most recent version. Next question... if I do an update now (to make subversion happy), will it overwrite my changes locally or give me the option to keep my version? (Sorry about the stupid beginner questions.)

Comment: If you have local changes and there is a newer version of the file, SVN will try to merge and ask you to merge manually if automatic merge fails. Also, you can try "cleanup" if you're think the file is up to date

Answer (score 0):

are you saying >> coming in the file name? if yes those are files created during possible conflict. You can delete them.

If that's not the case provide some screenshot if you can.

Comment: It's just a single ">" by the filename (indicating the file has changed). Thanks for the reply - BRPocock has got me on the right track  looking at the console window (above in comments).